# Recurring promotions in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I want my customers to have a 10% discount promotion every Monday. What's the best way to do that automatically without having to manually change the from/to dates each week?

All I can think of is a cron job that updates the start/end dates to Monday each week. Alternatively, I suppose I could add a "day" column to the promotions table and have whatever PHP checks the start/end dates to instead use the server time and check the day column to validate the promotion. I'm not sure where exactly that PHP is, though. Are either of these approaches better than the other, or is that the wrong way to go about it?

I'm running Magento 1.7 CE.

Comment: Do you use cart rules or catalog rules?

Comment: Cart rule, but if you know anything for a catalog rule, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a magento shell script to change the price rule. Here is the code to do that:

```
$nextMonday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next monday'));
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(YOUR_RULE_ID);
$rule->setFromDate($nextMonday)
        ->setToDate($nextMonday)
        ->save();
```

Call the script via cron once a week between 2 mondays and you're done!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I couldn't find this info elsewhere, but it's just what I was expecting. If I get this to work tonight, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0):

this is done with cron job facility of hosting server
it your website is hosted on hostgattor server
then login to cpanel
and type "cron" in search bar in cpanel
click on cron job
there is drop downs in which you have to choose time selections
and in action you have to type your page on which the code for updates the start/end date
e.g. "wget -q http;//www.yourdomain.com/yourpagename.extension"

Comment: I'm looking for advice on how to update the promotion via PHP, not how to use cron itself.